# iOS Simulator, CLLocationManager, startUpdatingLocation, and locationManager:didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager

I'm using iOS SDK7.1.

In my view controller's viewDidLoad method I create a CLLocationManager object and send it the startUpdatingLocation method.

In the iOS Simulator, I can change the location, and the locationManager:didUpdateLocations gets called.

However, it does not seem that locationManager:didUpdateLocations is called immediately after CLLocationManager object receives the startUpdatindgLocation method.

In the documentation for startUpdatingLocation in CLLocationManger it says:
*Calling this method causes the location manager to obtain an initial location fix (which may take several seconds) and notify your delegate by calling its locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method.*

Basically, I want to get the user's location before the user moves.

Comment: You _really_ want to be testing core location on a physical device, not in the simulator. Also keep in mind GPS functions better when it has a clear view of the sky... so some testing will have to be done outside rather than at your desk. Very annoying but there's no way around it.

Comment: I thought that the location services might use the WiFi to determine location if I was indoors and using the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You must set:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

In your info.plist

[image]